# Leaderboard not working Unity 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed the instructions in this link

http://shaneobrien.ie/official-google-play-game-services-plugin/

to assign the leaderboard on my game, but it does not work. My code for the leaderboard button:

```
public void LeaderBoard ()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log ("You've successfully logged in");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Login failed for some reason");
        }
    });

    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
        Social.ReportScore (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("BestScore"), leaderboard, (bool success) =>
        {
        if (success) {
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI (leaderboard);
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Login failed for some reason");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Log:

```
Login failed for some reason UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) 
LoadSceneScript:<LeaderBoard>m__EF(Boolean) (at Assets/Script/LoadSceneScript.cs:256)
GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DummyClient:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/BasicApi/DummyClient.cs:33) 
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:278) 
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:249) 
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs:48) 
LoadSceneScript:LeaderBoard() (at Assets/Script/LoadSceneScript.cs:251) 
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Comment: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/640 there are many suggestions on the prior page.

Comment: I also read it and saw a lot of people also have problems like me. But no one has the answer

Comment: So you signed the app and verified that it matches?  And you are signing in using a valid test user?  Google play services and sdk are all up to date?